# Sharepoint Custom List Preview Pane not displaying information past Title and Date

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

My preview pane has all the items down the left side as it should, and it has all of my column selections as rows down the right side.

However, when hovering over the titles, only `Date` and `Title` are being filled out on the right side.

If I change the view style to `boxed` or anything then it displays all the information.

It just appears that preview pane is having some weird difficulty correlating the hovered over item to the information on the right, Any suggestions?

Using Sharepoint 2013. I don't have Sharepoint Designer though. There's roughly 15 columns of information that needs to be displayed in rows because there's not enough room along the columns bar otherwise. Boxed style worked for a moment but then I realized there was no way to make it 1 box wide instead of default 2 boxes wide.

EDIT: I created a calendar view to add onto my page and chose to display Title. This might be where the problem is coming from. It says the title of all of my items are (no title).

Comment: I figured out that in InfoPath in the Fields pane on the right, you have to go to 'Show Advanced View'. Then there is a group called queryFields. The title inside queryFields was never being injected with same information as dataField.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that in InfoPath in the Fields pane on the right, you have to go to 'Show Advanced View'. Then there is a group called queryFields. The title inside queryFields was never being injected with same information as dataField. I saw later in the view option that my sort by setting was [Title]. I don't know if it's relevant, but putting it out there for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:  If you have an email user/group field that is not completed, it will not display any details beyond that field for each record.  Either remove that email column, or ensure they are filled out.